# get the column matching a word in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I want to use awk to get the column for an excel file where the column name is annotation. For example I have

```
data number annotation.1.2
1     2      where can I go
4     5      where can I see this flim
6     7      I want to see this movie.
```

`awk '$3 ~ /annotation/ { print }' toto`

My code works if the third column is annotation, but I have some other files where annotation is in fourth of fifth column. Is there any way to give as a pattern only annotation.1.3 ?

with the code below, I am receiving only
`film
can
where`

Comment: Is annotation always is last column? If not then you should let us know some other logic too by which we can recognize that how long its values could be? OR till when we need to fetch its values, column number we can get it but your samples shows you have spaces in between values in that case we need to know the exact logic of getting complete value, so please do let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed the requirement and told that Input_file is TAB delimited and annotations field's length is not fixed so adding following solution now.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="\t"
}
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/annotation/){
       val=i
       next
    }
  }
}
match($val,/[^\t]*/){
  print substr($val,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following(was written and tested as per OP's samples).

```
awk 'FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="annotation"){val=i;next}}} {print $val}' Input_file
```

In case you have different delimiter like TAB then change `awk` to `awk -v FS="\t"` in above code.

Comment: It also cuts the data I have in this column. I have different sentences but with this I receive only a few words.

Comment: @oezlem, kindly explain it more, I have only written and tested code as per provided examples by you, please be more clear.

Comment: This is good answer ++ OP probably has different delimiter instead of space.

Comment: I have sentences like
```Where can I see this film
what can I do
Where can I go```
But I receive only a few fords in a every line where, what, film.
Also the name of the column is annotation.1.2
Should I use something to be able to use the points ?

Comment: @oezlem, please update samples in your post only, with sample of input and expected output and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry Ravinder, I updated the result

Comment: @oezlem, Is annotation always is last column? If not then you should let us know some other logic too by which we can recognize that how long its values could be? OR till when we need to fetch its values, column number we can get it but your samples shows you have spaces in between values in that case we need to know the exact logic of getting complete value, so please do let us know.

Comment: no it is not always in the last column, that's why I am having problems. This is an excel file. Annotation is sometimes it is in the sixth column sometimes it is in the seventh column sometimes the fifth. In the column there are complete sentences, so I want to get the whole sentence in that column.

Comment: @oezlem, is your Input_file is TAB delimited and values for annotations will have only spaces NOT tabs in it?

Comment: @oezlem, could you please try my EDIT solution and let me know then?

Comment: Thank you Ravinder it worked, if you have time could you kindly explain it to me ? I am trying to learn

Comment: @oezlem, sure will add explanation in sometime.

Comment: @oezlem wrt `This is an excel file` - you can't parse an excel file using awk. You CAN parse tab-separated or comma-separated files as can be **exported** from Excel. Is that what you're working with or something else? When you say `it only has spaces` do you mean the field you're interested in only has blank chars while each line is tab-separated fields or something else?